# Node/Express function and callback are not breaking with return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, mongoose

I am creating a 'refresh data' function in Node and I cannot figure out where to place the callbacks and returns.  The function continues to run.  Below is a list of things the function should do.  Could someone help out?

1. Check if a user has an api id in the local MongoDB
2. Call REST api with POST to receive token
3. Store token results in a MongoDB
4. Terminate function

./routes/index.js

```
router.post('/refresh', function(req, res) {
    var refresh = require('../api/refresh');
    refresh(req, function() { return console.log('Done'); });
});
```

../api/refresh.js

```
var callToken = require('./calltoken');
var User = require('../models/user'); // Mongoose Schema

module.exports = function(req, callback) {
  User.findOne( {'username':req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) { console.log(err) }
    if (user.api_id == 0) {
      callToken.postToken(req.body.username, callback);
    } else { // Do something else }
  });
};
```

./calltoken.js

```
var request = require('request');
var Token = require('../models/token');  // Mongoose Schema

module.exports = {

  postToken: function(user, callback) {
    var send = {method:'POST', url:'address', formData:{name:user} };
    request(send, function(err, res, body) {
      if(err) { console.log(err) }
      if (res.statusCode == 201) { 
        var newToken = new Token();
        newToken.token = JSON.parse(body).access_token['token'];
        newToken.save(function(err) {
          if(err) { console.log(err) }
          return callback();
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: So if `res.statusCode` was not the expected result when would the callback be called and execution allowed to continue? Also it's bad practice to overwite the `res` in scope with your `request()` call. Both `res` and `req` are the scored variables of your endpoint request, and even though you are "testing" right now, you are going to want to use the `res` from that scope to return a "response" to the client.

Comment: Blakes, thank you for the quick response.  I removed the else statement for res.statusCode != 201 to simplify the posting, but if this situation occurred an error would be returned and the function stopped with no more callbacks.  I expect the process for refreshing data and error checking each step will be quite long once completed with many branches.  Also, I'll be sure to avoid overwriting res and will use res and req only for communicating with the client going forward.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Blakes, the problem was solved by async.series.  To simplify, I consolidated the code on the ./routes/index.js file within the route.  Thanks for your assistance and suggestions earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Express but everywhere in you code in lines with `if(err) { console.log(err) }` you should stop execution (maybe of course not - up to you app) and return 400 or 500 to client. So it can be something like

```
if(err) { 
  console.log(err);
  return callback(err);  // NOTICE return here
}
```

On successful execution you should call `return callback(null, result)`. Notice null as a first argument - it is according nodejs convention (error always goes as first argument).

Comment: Sergey, thank you very much.  I have changed this particular route to use async.series.  That said, your answer has helped me to understand how to appropriately use return and callbacks.  I have struggled with this topic despite reading and reviewing many examples.  Much appreciated!